# Integer Solutions to an Ellipse

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conic-sections

I'm trying to find positive integer solutions to the ellipse
$$x^2 - xy + y^2 - k^2 = 0$$
where $k$ is a constant. Specifically, I already have two solutions for a given $k$, and I'm trying to find a third, possibly by using the two known solutions. (I'm trying to copy the technique of producing rational solutions to a conic from one known rational point on the conic.)

I have searched a lot on the Internet, but most resources either suggest checking all values within the range of the ellipse's 'box', or give methods for a particular type of ellipse. *Edit:* I [found](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545859/140607) [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166332/140607) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513733/140607) [which](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1818495/140607) are similar to mine, but I cannot apply the technique used in them to my question mainly because I do not understand the technique. They all mention work by Fricke and Klein (1897).

My questions are:

- How many [positive] integer solutions does a general ellipse have?
- How can we find them? (From scratch, or knowing a few solutions beforehand?)

Comment: You'll find useful information in answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818495/solutions-to-a-quadratic-diophantine-equation-x2-xy-y2-3r2/1818693#1818693).

Comment: @Ghartal That question, and many other linked questions, are similar to mine but since none of them tell me what the "Fricke and Klein (1897)" method/theorem is, I cannot apply the same technique here.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: @individ I am having a little difficulty in understanding the method. What do you mean by "if the root of the whole", "if a root $\sqrt{fa}$", etc.?

Comment: In this case. $\sqrt{fa}=k$ It is possible to factorize and to consider all solutions.

Comment: @individ Then what are $p$ and $s$? You cannot solve the Pell equation because $b^2 - 4ac$ is negative.

Comment: So for a given number has infinitely many solutions no.

Comment: @individ So how do I find those solutions? How can there be infinitely many integer solutions?

Comment: Given $k$ the number of solutions of course. You can use some brute force to find the desired number   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816681/find-all-integers-satisfying-m2-n-12n-1n-2n-22/816685#816685

Comment: @individ Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41552/discussion-between-shardulc-and-individ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the number of prime factors of $k$ when we consider a factorization over the ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836578/find-the-sides-of-the-triangle/1837085#1837085), too. For instance, there are just trivial solutions if $k$ is a square-free number and a product of primes of the form $3m-1$, that do not split over $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. So the number of integer points on such ellipses has a very irregular arithmetic behaviour, but a quite regular behaviour on average, just like in the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the linked question had prompted me to ask this question :)

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^2-xy+y^2=k^2$ has a parametric solution given below,

$$x=p^2-q^2$$

$$y=2pq-q^2$$

$$k=p^2-pq+q^2$$

For $(p,q)=(3,2)$ we get $(x,y,k)=(5,8,7)$.

Comment: Consider using Mathjax for posting here.

Comment: See [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278439/rational-parametrization-of-a-conic/2278470#2278470).